# How to format a date that is a string in Luxon

Tags: luxon

given the following string: `2022-11-23`, how can I use `luxon` to format it to be `23-11-2022`

Answer (score 1):

Using Luxon, you can [parse](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing) your input string using [`fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=iso-8601) ([api-docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso)) and then format to your desired format using [`toFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=formatting-with-tokens-strings-for-cthulhu) ([api-docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoformat)) See [Table of tokens](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens) to get details on how to match part of the datetime with its cooresponding token.

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
console.log(DateTime.fromISO("2022-11-23").toFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.0.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

In your case, you can also avoid using Luxon and set up some string manipulation like the following:

```js
let parts = "2022-11-23".split('-');
console.log(parts[2] + '-' + parts[1] + '-' + parts[0]);
```